# Read values from a file, increment or change them and store them again in the same place

Tags: bash, awk, sed

So, I have a bash script which reads several variables from different external files, increments or changes these variables and then stores the new values in the files.

Something like this:

```
var1=$(< file1)
var2=$(< file2)
var3=$(< file3)

# then for example:
((var1=var1+1))
((var1=var1-1))
var3=foo

echo $var1 > file1
echo $var2 > file2
echo $var3 > file3
```

This works just fine, but I find it a bit bulky, especially when there are a lot of variables stored like this. I think it would be more elegant to store all the values in a single file which could look something like this:

```
#File containing values
var1=1
var2=2
var3=foo
```

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to read the values from such a file and store the new values in the same place afterwards? I have looked into `sed` and `awk` but so far I couldn't find a solution that works in this particular case.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: In general, UNIX semantics don't let you rewrite a file in-place line-by-line (which is to say, without rewriting the whole thing from the beginning after you no longer need to do any further reading of the old version) unless you're guaranteeing that the new lines are exactly the same length as the old ones. That's why `sed -i` (and, where available, `awk -i`) _doesn't_ rewrite in place -- it creates a new file, and renames it over the old one when it's done.

Comment: Also, note that there are security implications here. If you're putting assignments that are going to be `eval`ed or `source`ed in files, you need to be sure the values that are stored aren't going to have unwanted side effects. `printf %q` or, in newer versions of the shell, `"${var1@Q}"` can get towards where you want to go.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried to look into `printf %q` but I can't really figure out how to use it. Could you maybe give me a hint to point me in the right direction?

Comment: `emitVars() { for var; do printf '%s=%q\n' "$var" "${!var}"; done; }` lets you `emitVars var1 var2 var3`, f/e, in a way that trusts the variable names to be safe but doesn't trust the values. You can set `var1=$'\'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)'` and then `eval "$(emitVars var1)"` perfectly safely -- which otherwise isn't true when handling that deliberately-hostile value.

Comment: Thank you, but that's way above my head. I'll go with the solution I posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An awk script can handle this i.e. to find out all `name=value` lines, find all integer value and increment it:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="="} NF==2 && $2+0 == $2 {++$2} 1' file

#File containing values
var1=2
var2=3
var3=foo
```

If you want to save changes inline then use this `gnu-awk` command:

```sh
awk -i inplace 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="="} NF==2 && $2+0 == $2 {++$2} 1' file
```

**Explanation:**

- `FS=OFS="="`: Set input and output field separator to `=`
- `NF==2`: Number of fields are `2`
- `&&`: ANDed with
- `$2+0 == $2`: Find only numeric values
- `++$2`: increment 2nd field
- `1`: Print each line

Comment: Sorry, didn't have time to test it yet. Looks very promising, though. I'll get back to you onve I've looked into it. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so the first part reads all the values from the file and increments them, which is nice. But it it's not quite what I'm looking for because before incrementing I need ro read the original values from the file. The second command doesn't seem to work for me. I get 'awk: unknown option -i ignored'. I'm on macOS. Could that be the Problem?

Comment: Ok, but I need the value read from the file stored in the variables var1, var2 etc. which this doesn't seem to do. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I want to print the variables into the terminal with echo and then increment or change them and save the new value in the file.

Comment: That is exactly this command is doing. 1. read current string from file 2. increment them 3. save new values back in file. I suggest you test it once and let me know what exactly is not working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230794/discussion-between-agaton-sax-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, since my question appears to have been imprecise I accepted the answer by @anubhava as correct even though it didn't quite work for me. But it seems to be the correct answer to my question and pointed me in the right direction. Based on that answer I found a solution that works for me:

I now have a file named 'storage' containing all the variable names and values like this:

```
var1 1
var2 1
var3 foo
```

In my script there are three scenarios:

1. Incrementing or decrementing silently

A value is read from the file (by searching for the variable name and reading the last field in that line), silently incremented or decremented and saved to the file again:

```
awk '/var1/{++$NF} {print > "storage" }' storage # incrementing
awk '/var1/{--$NF} {print > "storage" }' storage # decrementing
```

2. Toggle between two values

Depending on user input a variable can be set to one of two values for example like this:

```
PS3="Please choose an option"
options=("Option 1" "Option 2")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Option 1")
            awk '/var2/{$NF=0} {print > "storage" }' storage # this sets the value to 0
            break
            ;;
        "Option 2")
            awk '/var2/{$NF=1} {print > "storage" }' storage # this sets the value to 1
            break
            ;;
    esac
done
```

3. Reading user input

The script reads a value from the file and prints it. Then it waits for user input and stores the input in the file

```
var3=$(awk '/var3/{print $NF}' storage) # reading the current value from the file and storing it in the variable
echo The current value is $var3
read -p "Please enter the new value" var3
awk -v var3="$var3" '/var3/{$NF=var3} {print > "storage" }' storage # writing the new value to the file
```

This does exactly what I was looking for. So, thank you @anubhava for pointing me in the right direction!